# ClassCastException when calling Clojure function

Tags: clojure

I have written the following bit of code

```
(defn create [title url]
  (when (not-any? clojure.string/blank? '(title url))
    (println "doing stuff")))
```

However when I call the function

```
(create "title" "url")
```

I get the following error and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence  clojure.string/blank? (string.clj:279)
```

Comment: If i change `'(title url)` to `(sequence [title url])` it works so clearly I am misunderstanding what the quote does.  Can someone explain or perhaps propose a better way (if it exists)?

Comment: Or better yet I can just use `[title url]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the things that also tripped me up when I first started learning clojure. Basically, you should use

```
(list title url)
```

The clojure compiler treats

```
'(title url)
```

as

```
(quote (title url))
```

'quote' does not evaluate anything inside of it, so 'title' and 'url' are just symbols (clojure.lang.Symbols to be precise).

Here's a better explanation than mine: http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html